# how to get a number from anyObject in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm working with JSON and I  errors code that I have to pass to my app and check it's value to tell the user what's wrong with his inputs 
so I have to take this error code and check it's value but my problem is that when I convert anyObject to NSNumber I get nil while the actual value (if I didn't convert the error code) isn't nil
so is there any way to get the numbers from anyObject and pass it to an int variable ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the integer value by using `object.integerValue`. It returns an optional. Or you can use `object as? Int`. Also returns an optional.